# Is it still legal to do pointer arithmetic on a deleted array?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

Today I wrote something which looked like this:

```
void foo(std::vector<char>&v){
    v.push_back('a');
    char*front=&v.front();
    char*back=&v.back();
    size_t n1=back-front+1;
    v.push_back('b');//This could reallocate the vector elements
    size_t n2=back-front+1;//Is this line valid or Undefined Behavior ?
}
```

**If a reallocation occures when I push 'b' back, may I still compute the difference of my two pointers ?**

After reading the relevant passage of the standard a few times, I still cannot make my mind on this point.

**C++11 5.7.6**:
When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the
subscripts of the two array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral
type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2). As
with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.
In other words, if the expressions P and Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array object,
the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i − j provided the value fits in an object of type std::ptrdiff_t.
Moreover, if the expression P points either to an element of an array object or one past the last element of
an array object, and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the expression
((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)), and has the value zero if the
expression P points one past the last element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
point to an element of the array object. **Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.**

Of course I know that it works, I just wonder if it is legal.

Comment: Doesn't a deleted object cease to be an object?

Comment: Since `front` and `back` may be dangling after `push_back`, that implies there is no array, and if there's no array, the two can't point to it. This potentially invokes UB.

Comment: Didn't anybody notice that it should be `back-front`, not `front-back`?

Comment: @Henrik I corrected the code

Comment: Even if the backing store of the vector is moved, the difference between the two address values won't change. In fact, an optimizing compiler could move the computation of n2 to before the push_back and not change the meaning of the program.

Comment: @jbruni That is an implementation detail. This question concerns the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointers to deleted objects are toxic: don't touch then for anything other than giving them a new value. A memory tracking system may trap aby use of a reclaimed pointer value. I'm not aware if any such system in existence, however.

The relevant quote is 3.7.4.2 [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation] paragraph 4:

> If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value, the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, rendering invalid all pointers to any part of the *deallocated storage*. The effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.

When resizing a `std::vector<...>` it jumps through a number of hoops (allocators) and, by default, eventually calls a deallocation function.

Comment: cargo cult programming.

Comment: @jbruni: I didn't have the time to add the relevant quote. However, my statement is solidly founded on the standard. The quote is added now.

Comment: +1: But is subtracting two pointers *using* those pointers?  ;)

Comment: @Yakk: Since the quote doesn't use _pointer_ but _pointer value_ there is very little room for interpretation, I'd think.

Comment: @jbruni I don't see how cargo cult applies. Do you maybe mean something else?

Comment: A bigger issue than memory tracking systems is compilers that may draw some rather "interesting" inferences based upon Undefined Behaviors in cases which would otherwise have had only benign consequences. I wish the Standard would specify a normative dialect of C which would forbid feeding invalid pointers to arithmetic operations that return pointers, but would guarantee that pointers to distinct objects of overlapping lifetimes would compare distinct, all pointers could be ranked, and pointers to the same dead object could be subtracted from each other and yield the same value as when live.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it's UB. But you can always convert your `char *` pointers to `uintptr_t` (provided it is present) and then safely subtract the resulting integers.

```
void foo(std::vector<char>&v){
    v.push_back('a');
    auto front= uintptr_t (&v.front());
    auto back = uintptr_t (&v.back());
    size_t n1=back-front+1;
    v.push_back('b');//This could reallocate the vector elements
    size_t n2=back-front+1;
}
```

Comment: However, now there's no guarantee that the result is meaningful.

Comment: But, _why_?  This may be _defined_ behavior, but almost certainly not what someone would want.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I've actually worked on systems where converting pointers to integers yielded values that were not meaningfully related to the pointer values; for example, `(uintptr_t)p1 - (uintptr_t)p0` might yield a completely different and meaningless result than `(char*)p1 - (char*)p0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, what was the reason for it?

Comment: @chill: Cray vector systems (C90, T90, SV1). The machines were 64-bit word addressed, with no hardware support for 8-bit byte access, so a machine was a 64-bit pointer to a 64-bit word. But the systems ran Unix, so it was necessary to support 8-bit bytes (C permits `CHAR_BIT==64`, but POSIX doesn't, and interoperability would have been a nightmare). So the C compiler implemented byte pointers *in software* by storing a 3-bit byte offset in the otherwise unused 3 high-order bits of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This particular case is safe but ugly and misleading.

Line `v.push_back('b');//This could reallocate the vector elements` can cause reallocation of your container. In this case next line will use a non existent `front` and `back` pointers. Computing difference of two addresses is safe even if are dangling pointers. What is not safe is dereferencing them.

The correct solution is to use `vector::count()` function the will be always in sync. If you (for some reason) don;t want to call `vector::count()` you should at leas use `++n1`.

Comment: It's only safe until it stops being. Treating this as safe assumes compilers won't get smarter.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic remains pointer arithmetic. Playing with pointer values is safe. There is no (smart) scenario that can lead to dereference pointer (and crash) when doing pointer arithmetic. As i pointed, the correct solution is to use `vector::count()`

Comment: Who said anything about crashes? There are other undesired behaviours that could result from a smart compiler (say, entirely removing an operation involving such bad pointers because it obviously must be dead code: a well-behaved program that follows C++ rules would not execute it, therefore it must be dead). Undefined behaviour is not about crashes.